# How to make an object move through an array of objects on keypress?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, oop, pygame

Here is all of my code:

```
import random as random

import pygame as pygame

pygame.init()  # initialize
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # framerate limit
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 1000])  # Create screen object and Window Size
Done = False
MapSize = 25

TileWidth = 20
TileHeight = 20
TileMargin = 4

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)


class MapTile(object):
    def __init__(self, Name, xlocation, ylocation):
        self.Name = Name
        self.xlocation = xlocation
        self.ylocation = ylocation


class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, Name, HP, Allegiance, xlocation, ylocation):
        self.Name = Name
        self.HP = HP
        self.Allegiance = Allegiance
        self.xlocation = xlocation
        self.ylocation = ylocation

    def Move(self, Direction):
        if Direction == "UP":
            self.ylocation += 1

        elif Direction == "LEFT":
            self.xlocation -= 1

        elif Direction == "RIGHT":
            self.xlocation += 1

        elif Direction == "DOWN":
            self.ylocation -= 1

        self.Location()

    def Location(self):
        print("Coordinates: " + str(self.xlocation) + ", " + str(self.ylocation))




class Map(object):
    Grid = []
    global MapSize

    for Row in range(MapSize):  # Creating grid
        Grid.append([])
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            Grid[Row].append([])

    for Row in range(MapSize):     #Filling grid with grass
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            TempTile = MapTile("Grass", Row, Column)
            Grid[Row][Column].append(TempTile)

    for Row in range(MapSize):     #Rocks
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            TempTile = MapTile("Rock", Row, Column)
            if Row == 1:
                Grid[Row][Column].append(TempTile)

    for i in range(10):       #Random trees
        RandomRow = random.randint(0, MapSize - 1)
        RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MapSize - 1)
        TempTile = MapTile("Tree", Row, Column)
        Grid[RandomRow][RandomColumn].append(TempTile)



    def update(self):
        for Row in range(MapSize):
            for Column in range(MapSize):
                for i in range(len(Map.Grid[Row][Column])):
                    if Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].xlocation != Column:
                        print("BOOP")
                        Map.Grid[Row][Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].xlocation].append(Map.Grid[Row][Column][i])
                        Map.Grid.remove(Map.Grid[Row][Column][i])

                    if Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].ylocation != Row:
                        print("BOOP")
                        Map.Grid[Row][Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].xlocation].append(Map.Grid[Row][Column][i])

                    else:
                        break

    RandomRow = random.randint(0, MapSize - 1)
    RandomColumn = random.randint(0, MapSize - 1)
    Hero = Character("boop", 10, "Friendly", RandomRow, RandomColumn)
    Grid[RandomRow][RandomColumn].append(Hero)


Map = Map()

while not Done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            Done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            Column = Pos[0] // (TileWidth + TileMargin)
            Row = Pos[1] // (TileHeight + TileMargin)
            print(str(Row) + ", " + str(Column))

            for i in range(len(Map.Grid[Row][Column])):
                print(str(Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].Name))

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Map.Hero.Move("LEFT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Map.Hero.Move("RIGHT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                Map.Hero.Move("UP")
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                Map.Hero.Move("DOWN")

            Map.update()


    Screen.fill(BLACK)

    for Row in range(MapSize):  # Drawing grid
        for Column in range(MapSize):
            Color = WHITE
            if len(Map.Grid[Row][Column]) == 2:
                Color = RED
            for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[Row][Column])):
                if Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].Name == "boop":
                    Color = GREEN
                if Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].Name == "MoveTile":
                    Color = BLUE

            pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TileMargin + TileWidth) * Column + TileMargin,
                                             (TileMargin + TileHeight) * Row + TileMargin,
                                             TileWidth,
                                             TileHeight])

    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

And the relevant bits:

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Map.Hero.Move("LEFT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Map.Hero.Move("RIGHT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                Map.Hero.Move("UP")
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                Map.Hero.Move("DOWN")

            Map.update()
```

The move function:

```
def Move(self, Direction):
            if Direction == "UP":
                self.ylocation += 1

            elif Direction == "LEFT":
                self.xlocation -= 1

            elif Direction == "RIGHT":
                self.xlocation += 1

            elif Direction == "DOWN":
                self.ylocation -= 1
```

And the update function, where the problem lies:

```
def update(self):
            for Row in range(MapSize):
                for Column in range(MapSize):
                    for i in range(len(Map.Grid[Row][Column])):
                        if Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].xlocation != Column:
                            print("BOOP")
                            Map.Grid[Row][Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].xlocation].append(Map.Grid[Row][Column][i])
                            Map.Grid.remove(Map.Grid[Row][Column][i])

                        if Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].ylocation != Row:
                            print("BOOP")
                            Map.Grid[Row][Map.Grid[Row][Column][i].xlocation].append(Map.Grid[Row][Column][i])

                        else:
                            break
```

The intended behavior of the update function is to check every object in the grid and see if it has moved (if there is a discrepancy between the object's internal coordinates and its current position on the grid), and replace it in the grid at its proper position. It does this by appending a new version of the object at the new location and deleting the old one.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/Monster.py", line 136, in <module>
    Map.update()
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/Monster.py", line 93, in update
    Map.Grid.remove(Map.Grid[Row][Column][i])
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

How best could I achieve the intended behavior?

Comment: The error you're getting is because `Map.Grid.remove()` looks for the value only in the first dimension of the list, which only contains other lists representing the second dimension — so it never finds the corresponding `MapTile` instance referenced. You need to loop through each sublist and `try` to remove the target (and quit looping when/if you do).

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax of doing that? Also, I'm not looking to remove the MapTile but the Hero. I want to move the hero through the grid by appending him in the new location and removing the old instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for undeleting your question so I could post an answer. Sorry it took so long for me to get back to you on this — hopefully it's not too late to be helpful.

Below is a heavily revised (but working) version of the code in your question. One of the things that slowed me down was that you weren't following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations, which made your version of the code difficult for me to read and understand. The general lack of comments explaining what was going on, especially in certain parts, didn't make it any easier.

The `Map.update()` method is where I implemented something somewhat like I described in my comment under your question about how to fix the `ValueError` problem.

```
import pygame as pygame
import random as random
import sys

GRASS_NAME = "Grass"
HERO_NAME = "Hero"
MOVETILE_NAME = "MoveTile"
ROCK_NAME = "Rock"
TREE_NAME = "Tree"
MAP_SIZE = 25
TILE_WIDTH = 20
TILE_HEIGHT = 20
TILE_MARGIN = 4
TILE_SIZE = TILE_WIDTH+TILE_MARGIN
BLACK = 0, 0, 0
WHITE = 255, 255, 255
GREEN = 0, 255, 0
RED = 255, 0, 0
BLUE = 0, 0, 255
YELLOW = 255, 255, 0
BROWN = 128, 128, 0
UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT = 0, 1, 2, 3
MOVEMENTS = {UP: (-1, 0), DOWN: (1, 0), LEFT: (0, -1,), RIGHT: (0, 1)}
MOVEMENT_KEYS = {pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN}

def quit_game():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

class MapTile(object):
    def __init__(self, name, xloc, yloc):
        self.name = name
        self.xloc = xloc
        self.yloc = yloc

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, allegiance, xloc, yloc):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.allegiance = allegiance
        self.xloc = xloc
        self.yloc = yloc

    def move(self, direction):
        dy, dx = MOVEMENTS[direction]
        self.yloc += dy
        self.xloc += dx

        # Enforce boundaries
        if self.xloc < 0:
            self.xloc = 0
        elif self.xloc > MAP_SIZE-1:
            self.xloc = MAP_SIZE-1

        if self.yloc < 0:
            self.yloc = 0
        elif self.yloc > MAP_SIZE-1:
            self.yloc = MAP_SIZE-1

        self.location()

    def location(self):
        print("{} coordinates: ({}, {})".format(self.name, self.xloc, self.yloc))

class Map(object):
    # Initialize grid
    grid = [[[] for column in range(MAP_SIZE)] for row in range(MAP_SIZE)]

    for row in range(MAP_SIZE):     # Completely fill grid with grass
        for column in range(MAP_SIZE):
            grid[row][column].append(MapTile(GRASS_NAME, column, row))

    # Add row of rocks near top
    row = 1
    for column in range(MAP_SIZE):
        grid[row][column].append(MapTile(ROCK_NAME, column, row))

    for _ in range(10):  # Add some random trees
        row, column = random.randint(0, MAP_SIZE-1), random.randint(0, MAP_SIZE-1)
        grid[row][column].append(MapTile(TREE_NAME, column, row))

    # Put hero character in random location
    row, column = random.randint(0, MAP_SIZE-1), random.randint(0, MAP_SIZE-1)
    hero = Character(HERO_NAME, 10, "Friendly", column, row)
    grid[row][column].append(hero)

    del row, column  # clean up class context

    def update(self):
        """Check every object in the grid and see if it has moved (if there is a
        discrepancy between the object's internal coordinates and its current
        position on the grid), and if so put it in its proper place by deleting
        it from its old list and appending it to the one for the proper location.
        """
        for row in range(MAP_SIZE):
            for column in range(MAP_SIZE):
                for i, object in enumerate(map.grid[row][column]):
                    if object.xloc != column or object.yloc != row: # wrong spot?
                        #print("BOOP")
                        map.grid[row][column].pop(i)
                        map.grid[object.yloc][object.xloc].append(object)

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # to limit framerate
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 1000])
map = Map()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit_game()
        elif(event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN
             and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]):  # button1 pressed?
            xpos, ypos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column, row = xpos // TILE_SIZE, ypos // TILE_SIZE
            if 0 <= column < MAP_SIZE and 0 <= row < MAP_SIZE:  # on map?
                print(str(row) + ", " + str(column))
                for i in range(len(map.grid[row][column])):
                    print(str(map.grid[row][column][i].name))
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key in MOVEMENT_KEYS:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    map.hero.move(LEFT)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    map.hero.move(RIGHT)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    map.hero.move(UP)
                else:
                    map.hero.move(DOWN)
                map.update()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quit_game()

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Draw grid
    for row in range(MAP_SIZE):
        for column in range(MAP_SIZE):
            # Determine color based on objects in this spot
            names = {object.name for object in map.grid[row][column]}
            color = WHITE  # default color (Grass)
            if HERO_NAME in names:
                color = YELLOW
            elif MOVETILE_NAME in names:
                color = BLUE
            elif TREE_NAME in names:
                color = GREEN
            elif ROCK_NAME in names:
                color = RED

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,
                             [TILE_SIZE*column + TILE_MARGIN,
                              TILE_SIZE*row + TILE_MARGIN,
                              TILE_WIDTH,
                              TILE_HEIGHT])

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```